# Get a random row from sql table and random value from array and alert this on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, sql, ajax

I got a table with names and some int value for each name, now I want to get a random name and a random value x from this int (like random(int * 0,7 < x < int). I also want to get a random value from an array and then display this with something like an alert when I press a button om my page.

I know I can use:

```
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
```

to get the random value from the array and:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM TABLE ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1";
```

to get a random row from the table but how to I randomize the int value from the row and display all this on a button click?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, as formatted text (no images.)

Comment: Im using mySQL. i got one column named club and one distance so a row could look like: driver, 250